# Use of RedisConfig DefaultPoolSizeMultiplier property in RedisPoolManager

Tags: servicestack, azure-redis-cache, servicestack.redis

**DefaultPoolSizeMultiplier** & **DefaultMaxPoolSize** property of RedisConfig in ServiceStack.Redis.
I didn't find any detailed documentation of **RedisConfig** properties.
I think **DefaultMaxPoolSize**, determines the no. of  redisClient a RedisPoolManager can have. But not sure about the use of **DefaultPoolSizeMultiplier**

```
Default Max Pool Size for Pooled Redis Client Managers (default none)
public static int? DefaultMaxPoolSize;

The default pool size multiplier if no pool size is specified (default 50)
public static int DefaultPoolSizeMultiplier = 50;
```

```
public class RedisClientManager
{
    private readonly List<RedisManagerPool> pooledClientmanagers = new List<RedisManagerPool>();
    private const int clientPoolSize = 50;
    public RedisClientManager()
    {
        RedisConfig.DefaultRetryTimeout = 5000;
        RedisConfig.BackOffMultiplier = 2;
        RedisConfig.DefaultIdleTimeOutSecs = 600;
        RedisConfig.DefaultMaxPoolSize = clientPoolSize;
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
            {
                var redisManagerPool = new RedisManagerPool
                    (RedisConnectionString);
                this.pooledClientmanagers.Add(redisManagerPool);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    public IRedisClient GetRedisClient()
    {
        IRedisClient client = null;
        foreach (var poolManager in pooledClientmanagers)
        {
            if ((poolManager.GetClientPoolActiveStates().Where(x => x == 0).Any()) ||
                (poolManager.GetStats().ContainsKey("clientsInUse") && Convert.ToInt32(poolManager.GetStats().GetValueOrDefault("clientsInUse")) < clientPoolSize))
            {
                client = poolManager.GetClient();
                var clientName = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName}_{poolManager.GetId()}_{AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()}";
                client.SetClient(clientName);
                break;
            }
        }
        return client;
    }
}
```

If anyone can help me out with their usage. If I want to need 1000 active redisClient all the time which one is recommended approach:

1. One Singleton registered RedisPoolManager with DefaultMaxPoolSize as 1000(for maintainig 1000 RedisClient)  (Is there any limit of DefaultMaxPoolSize?)

2. Static List of 20 RedisPoolManager with DefaultMaxPoolSize as 50(for maintainig 50 RedisClient)

[mythz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85785/mythz) Could you please provide your insight..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only ever have a **singleton instance** of a [Redis Client Manager](https://docs.servicestack.net/redis/client-managers#redis-client-managers) to ensure your App is sharing from the same pooled redis client connections.

Multiplier just means how big the pool size is relative to the configured redis hosts, e.g. for **master** server there's only a single instance so the multiplier just determines the pool size for redis clients connected to the master instance.

Instead of using a multiplier you can use the [Redis Configuration](https://docs.servicestack.net/redis/client-managers#redis-configuration) class to set an exact pool size for both read/write and read only client pools:

##### Configure Pool Size of Redis Client Managers

```cs
RedisConfig.DefaultMaxPoolSize = 100;
```

Comment: Yeah, @mythz I have registered the RedisClientManager as singleton. So if I have understood correctly, then multiplier will be used in case we don't specify DefaultMaxPoolSize. And if my service demands 1000 connection at a given point of time, then I shld maintain single RedisPoolManager with 1000 DefaultMaxPoolSize.

Comment: reg. DefaultIdleTimeOutSecs when I am using its default value of 240. I have observed, that client connection is present under connected_clients till 10 mins(600 secs). I was hoping it be removed after 240 but its still there when I run redis-cli CLIENT LIST. Is it bcoz 10 min is the idle timeout set at Redis Server side? How Can I override it at client side

Comment: You don't want the pool size to be max peak concurrent size, you want it to be a bit more than your concurrent load average so pooled collections are being reused. You can check `TotalClientsCreated` in [Redis Stats](https://docs.servicestack.net/redis/stats) to show how many clients were created outside of the pool. It should be sufficient to meet your avg load, and grow at peak loads.

Comment: There's no background thread which auto expires clients after `DefaultIdleTimeOutSecs` is exceeded, only when clients are resolved from pool will it reconnect after it's been idle for that long. You'll want this to be configured to be a bit smaller than the Redis Server timeout.

Comment: So if my avg concurrent load is 500 then I should atleast set `DefaultMaxPoolSize` to bit more than 500 say 600. In case of peak concurrent load(1000), it will create 400 unmanaged redisclient which I can see in `TotalClientsCreatedOutsidePool` and for total clients under that RedisPoolManager I should refer `TotalClientsCreated`.

Comment: Apologize @mythz If I completely mis-understood the following statement `after DefaultIdleTimeOutSecs is exceeded, only when clients are resolved from pool will it reconnect after it's been idle for that long.` Does this mean, if `DefaultIdleTimeOutSecs` is 240 than post 240 seconds, the Idle RedisClient(MANAGED) will be reconnected with Redis Server in order to keep their TCP Connection alive. So keeping `DefaultIdleTimeOutSecs`  too low, will have pref. impact. And does the same will happen with UnManaged Idle RedisClient?
Let me knw, if I should create another thread, for this question.

Comment: The server controls the timeout, the client should just be configured below the server timeout so that it doesn't need to wait for the client to fail and reconnect, when it can just reconnect elapsed idle connections immediately. There's negligible performance impact since high volume sites wont hit the idle timeout and creating tcp connections is cheap in Redis for low volume sites which have idle connection timeouts.